# What is proper #include syntax with javascript variable in aspx page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

A JavaScript function returns a virtual path and filename of an HTML file that I want included in the page, 
How do i use the JavaScript variable in the include statement ??

here is the code:

```html
<div id="vcontainer" runat="server" >
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var srcFile = "~/Views/D1C1.html";

// this works <!--#include virtual="~/Views/D1C1.html" -->
this doesn't  <!--#include virtual=srcFile -->

</script>
</div>
```